# Getting ClassCastException in oracle 10g express edition.

Tags: java

I am trying connect to a database table and getting 
`java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement cannot be cast to java.beans.Statement`in oracle 10g express edition

```
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        System.out.println("Driver loaded.");

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","toushif");
        System.out.println("Connection Established.");
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM  TOUSHIF";

        Statement st = (Statement) con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = ((java.sql.Statement) st).executeQuery(sql);

        while(rs.next())
        {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

`con.createStatement()` should return an implementation of `java.sql.Statement` and not of `java.beans.Statement`.

Maybe you imported `java.beans.Statement` instead of `java.sql.Statement` which causes the cast to fail?